# Are there Clang flags that are only for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, clang, compiler-flags

Simple question, but I can't find the answer in the Clang documentation.

Are there any Clang compiler flags that are only for Objective-C? Objective-C seems to share many flags with C, but I imagine that it has many flags of its own.

Comment: `clang --help | grep -i objc`

Answer (score 2):

You can see all the flags with the `--help` option, then filter them with `grep`. Any items relevant to Objective-C will contain "objc". Thus

```
clang --help | grep -i objc
```

should always get you the current list.